# Jmeter test in Jenkins fails with "errorlevel=255" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, jmeter

I am trying to run jmeter test from windows command line using Jenkins and getting an error at build step. The error is:

`"  errorlevel=255 Press any key to continue . . . Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure"`

**The executable windows batch command is:**

```
C:\Ankush\PerformanceTesting\apache-jmeter-3.3\apache-jmeter-
3.3\bin\jmeter.bat -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -n -t 
C:\Users\a.panday\git\performance-tests\dwp.jmx -l 
C:\Ankush\PerformanceTesting\Results\Test.csv -j test_local.log ^
-JthinkTime=500 ^
-JthreadDelay=1000 ^
-Jdwpserver= abc.bac.com^
-Juserid= abc ^
-Jpassword= abc ^
-Jprotocol=https ^
-Jtc1RenewalsSelectionCriteriaEndDateFrom= ^
-Jtc1RenewalsSelectionCriteriaEndDateTo= ^
-JtimeOutInSecondsForPassiveRenewalsTC1Jobs= ^
-JdelayInMilisecondsBeforeCheckingOrdersInJbillingForTC1PR= ^
-Jrampup=2 ^
-Jloopcount=1 ^
-Jrenewalthread=0 ^
-Jtest_load_Account_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_List_of_contracts_sales_marketing_menu=1 ^
-Jtest_load_List_of_contracts_contract_switching_menu=1 ^
-Jtest_load_List_of_contracts_contract_switching_menu_filtered=1 ^
-Jtest_load_List_quotes_sales_marketing_menu=1 ^
-Jtest_load_List_quotes_sales_marketing_menu_filtered=1 ^
-Jtest_load_account_cockpit_billing_And_InvoiceDetails=1 ^
-Jtest_load_Contract_details_page=1 ^
-Jtest_load_Quote_details_page=1 ^
-Jtest_load_creation_and_saving_of_a_guidance_flow=1 ^
-Jtest_load_creation_of_a_quote_cqfa=1 ^
-Jtest_load_determine_quote_price=1 ^
-Jtest_load_creation_of_a_case=1 ^
-Jtest_load_creation_and_saving_of_a_guidance_flow_B2C=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_task_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_filter_ean_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_filter_account_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_filter_status_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_task_filter_ean_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_task_filter_account_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_task_filter_status_screen=1 ^
-Jtest_load_market_transaction_task_restart=1 ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.label=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.time=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true ^
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`
```

The above command is running fine in windows command line perfectly but giving the stated error while building in Jenkins.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if i run without adding Jmeter parameters, it runs fine. Only when i add Jmeter parameters, it fails. I am not sure if this is related to user permissions as everything is local and I am the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice you have spaces between = sign and property value

-Jdwpserver=**SPACE**abc.bac.com^

You such space which prevent JMeter execution in the following properties:

```
-Jdwpserver= abc.bac.com^
-Juserid= abc ^
-Jpassword= abc ^

-Jtc1RenewalsSelectionCriteriaEndDateFrom= ^
-Jtc1RenewalsSelectionCriteriaEndDateTo= ^
-JtimeOutInSecondsForPassiveRenewalsTC1Jobs= ^
-JdelayInMilisecondsBeforeCheckingOrdersInJbillingForTC1PR= ^
```

Just remove the spaces and it will work

Comment: the space existed while removing the server details, in real there are no spaces. it only happened during giving the dummy values.

Comment: Removing spaces between = and ^ resolved this issue. Thanks for the idea.